# bind python/flask module app yo WINDOWS Server IIS

Tags: python, flask, iis

I’m a novice python developer with very basic knowledge of this platform. We received a python app developed on Mac/Linux from a 3rd parry (consultant company),  and I’m having trouble bind it to IIS on a WINDOWS WEB server.

Setting:

- Python 3.8.1, deploying flask and dash
- Windows server 2012R2
- IIS 8.5

Configuration:

- FastCgi setting on IIS :
  [image]
- Create a site under IIS  (port 8051 in my test) and set the physical path to the folder where the runserver.py  and web.config files reside.
  [image]

[image]

- The rest of the configuration is administrated by a web.config file at the app’s root folder.

Successful Simple Test

- I successfully implemented a simple test file as follow:

**runserver.py**

```
                from flask import Flask
            app = Flask(__name__)

            from datetime import datetime 
            from urllib.parse import urlparse
            from flask import request
             
            import socket

            app.debug = True

            @app.route('/')
            def kuki():    
                return "Hello from flask over IIS. host:[{}],  url:[{}],  TS:[{}]".format(socket.gethostname(), request.base_url, datetime.now())

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                app.run()
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PythonHandler" />
            <add    
                    name="PythonHandler" 
                    path="*" 
                    verb="*" 
                    modules="FastCgiModule" 
                    scriptProcessor="c:\python3_8_1\python.exe|c:\python3_8_1\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
                    resourceType="Unspecified" 
                    requireAccess="Script" 
            />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\_MyPython\HelloFlask" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="runserver.app" />
        <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\_MyPython\HelloFlask\log\HelloFlask.log" />
    </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

Problem running the full python app

- An application folder reside under the app’s root folder
  [image]
  [image]
- The ***py -m application*** command is successfully  launching the service
- Can someone advice how to set the web.config file to enable successful IIS binding?

Thanks,

Shaul

Comment: "We received a python app developed on Mac/Linux" then you must host it on Linux. Microsoft has deprecated all its efforts to run Python web apps on IIS/Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

index.py:

```
# Import Application level packages
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# Import other neccessary classes, objects in project
from app import dash_app
from xxx import XXX
...
...

# Import Application dependent packages
import random
from datetime import date
random.seed(date.today())

# Set the app's HTML title
dash_app.title = "**** *****"

# Set the app's overall layout. 
# Each Content Element is imported by reference and 
# elements in each container will change dynamically (when respective callback is fired) as user enters inputs.
dash_app.layout = html.Div(
    ....
    ....
    ....
)

ContentElement.init_all_callbacks(skip=[])

# Start flask server
flask_app = dash_app.server

# Run application
def run():

    # open webbrowser automatically:
    if Config.AUTOOPEN:
        import threading, webbrowser
        url = f"http://{Config.HOST}:{Config.PORT}"
        # Wait for 2.25 seconds initially for dash to process the app initially
        threading.Timer(2.25, lambda: webbrowser.open(url)).start()

    # Add debug=Config.DEBUG as a parameter in order to debug in front-end
    dash_app.run_server(host=Config.HOST, port=Config.PORT)
```

---

app.py:

```
# Import OS level packages
import os

# Import Application level packages
from flask import send_from_directory
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# Pull in bootstrap darkly stylesheet
external_stylesheets = [
    r"assets/bootstrap_style.css"
]

# Create instance of dash app
dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, url_base_pathname=Config.URL_BASE_PATH)

# Create instance of dash server
server = dash_app.server
```

---

Created a new entry_point.py :

```
import app

from index import flask_app

from index import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main entry point for app
    run()
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PythonHandler"/>
            <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\python3_8_1\python.exe|c:\python3_8_1\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
                resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\_MyPython\TCO_WIP2\TCO"/>
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="entry_point.flask_app"/>
        <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\_MyPython\TCO_WIP2\TCO\Log\TCO_WIP2.log"/>
    </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

Thanks,

Shaul